# Z3 is unable to predict the operand

Tags: ida, crackme

When I try to solve this crackme chall (https://crackmes.one/crackme/61ffb07c33c5d46c8bcbfc1d) , there is a condition that I can't bypass and my z3 script can't predict the input string that will bypass the condition

[image]

and this is my z3 script

```
from z3 import *

v7 = [123,456,789,987,654,321]
v6 = [92,29,380,2,497,296]

s = [BitVec(f'a{i}', 8) for i in range(5)]

solver = Solver()

v20 = 0x7FFFFFFF
for i in range(5):
    solver.add(s[i]>32,s[i]<127)
    v20 += i * s[i]
    solver.add(v20 % v7[i] == v6[i])

solver.check()
```

Comment: The function has much more logic and you need to add that in the script too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is to note that the division in the binary is unsigned while according to [doc](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3py_1_1_bit_vec_ref.html#a972c1bf635b9697a3d92d066e0ebe10c)

> Use the function URem() for unsigned remainder, and SRem() for signed remainder.

`%` operator by default is an alias for `SRem` or signed modulo. You need to use `URem`. I have fixed your logic as well in this code

```
from z3 import *

v7 = [123,456,789,987,654,321]
v6 = [92,29,380,2,497,296]
arrl = 14
argv1 = [BitVec(f'a{i}', 32) for i in range(arrl)]

solver = Solver()
v18 = BitVecVal(0x7fffffff, 32)

for i in range(arrl):
    solver.add(argv1[i] < 128)
    solver.add(argv1[i] > 32)
    v18 += i*argv1[i]

for i in range(6):
    solver.add(URem(v18, v7[i]) == v6[i])

print(solver.check())
print("".join(map(chr,[solver.model()[argv1[i]].as_long() for i in range(arrl)])))
```

Please note that this won't solve the problem, It has additional checks.

Comment: Thanks! as you see there is `if ( ((unsigned int (__fastcall *)(char *, size_t))v14)(a2[1], v5) )` in decompiled code, can you explain what this check do ? and what does this mean `(unsigned int (__fastcall *)(char *, size_t))` ?

Comment: @IntVer You can open a new question for that. hint: its a function pointer

Comment: @sudhacker https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30308/decompilers-points-to-non-existing-virtual-function