# Decompilers points to non-existing virtual function

Tags: ida, pointer, vtables, virtual-functions

As part of solving the [Hidden password](https://crackmes.one/crackme/61ffb07c33c5d46c8bcbfc1d) challenge, I found an condition calls a virtual function

[image]

the `v14` points to `v8` variable :

[image]

and the functions in the program does not make sense for me, there is no two-args functions in binary program, does this bytes mean something such as signatures/evaluable code/etc..

```
  v8[0] = 0x28BF16683619A05BLL;
  v8[1] = 0x4DD3CE3A2552E799LL;
  v8[2] = 0xA5ED9BE182304449LL;
  v8[3] = 0x6E27E1473B191037LL;
  v8[4] = 0x6DA9EC4E7AC0DAECLL;
  v8[5] = 0x8929723C31C59039LL;
  v8[6] = 0xEA92AC15DE3C3F69LL;
  v8[7] = 0x828DD2F713F6E8BELL;
  v8[8] = 0xBB4D607B1C553C6FLL;
  v8[9] = 0x7DC2D2F3EC43EF5BLL;
  v8[10] = 0x4DAF64150084DC96LL;
  v8[11] = 0xE1F1361E21C67AB9LL;
  v8[12] = 0xA4B498C90BE95F82LL;
  v8[13] = 0xB439B94451F266B5LL;
  v8[14] = 0x2380C814A4F0145BLL;
  v8[15] = 0x808581A5B7FB9D7ELL;
  v8[16] = 0x589B2B23881C5633LL;
  v8[17] = 0xBBAA188D8CDE35D8LL;
  v8[18] = 0xF6F8FD3AEB6DD0D2LL;
  v8[19] = 0x2FEAA6B6AE8530B8LL;
  v8[20] = 0xB30EDC56B009E85FLL;
  v8[21] = 0xFBD9E747FFC36C8FLL;
  v8[22] = 0x18194F7045E8F66LL;
  v8[23] = 0xC27B4D434FE8BEEALL;
```

```
code = [
    0x28,0xBF,0x16,0x68,0x36,0x19,0xA0,0x5B,
    0x4D,0xD3,0xCE,0x3A,0x25,0x52,0xE7,0x99,
    0xA5,0xED,0x9B,0xE1,0x82,0x30,0x44,0x49,
    0x6E,0x27,0xE1,0x47,0x3B,0x19,0x10,0x37,
    0x6D,0xA9,0xEC,0x4E,0x7A,0xC0,0xDA,0xEC,
    0x89,0x29,0x72,0x3C,0x31,0xC5,0x90,0x39,
    0xEA,0x92,0xAC,0x15,0xDE,0x3C,0x3F,0x69,
    0x82,0x8D,0xD2,0xF7,0x13,0xF6,0xE8,0xBE,
    0xBB,0x4D,0x60,0x7B,0x1C,0x55,0x3C,0x6F,
    0x7D,0xC2,0xD2,0xF3,0xEC,0x43,0xEF,0x5B,
    0x4D,0xAF,0x64,0x15,0x00,0x84,0xDC,0x96,
    0xE1,0xF1,0x36,0x1E,0x21,0xC6,0x7A,0xB9,
    0xA4,0xB4,0x98,0xC9,0x0B,0xE9,0x5F,0x82,
    0xB4,0x39,0xB9,0x44,0x51,0xF2,0x66,0xB5,
    0x23,0x80,0xC8,0x14,0xA4,0xF0,0x14,0x5B,
    0x80,0x85,0x81,0xA5,0xB7,0xFB,0x9D,0x7E,
    0x58,0x9B,0x2B,0x23,0x88,0x1C,0x56,0x33,
    0xBB,0xAA,0x18,0x8D,0x8C,0xDE,0x35,0xD8,
    0xF6,0xF8,0xFD,0x3A,0xEB,0x6D,0xD0,0xD2,
    0x2F,0xEA,0xA6,0xB6,0xAE,0x85,0x30,0xB8,
    0xB3,0x0E,0xDC,0x56,0xB0,0x09,0xE8,0x5F,
    0xFB,0xD9,0xE7,0x47,0xFF,0xC3,0x6C,0x8F,
    0x18,0x19,0x4F,0x70,0x45,0xE8,0xF6,0x6,
    0xC2,0x7B,0x4D,0x43,0x4F,0xE8,0xBE,0xEA,
    0xcb,0x87,0xce,0xb3
]
```

and the XOR part `*((_BYTE *)v8 + (int)k) ^= v11;` XOR with the key generated by other function

```
unsigned __int64 sub_1169()
{
  // qword_4040 -> 0x1
  qword_4040 = 1103515245 * qword_4040 + 12345;
  return ((unsigned __int64)qword_4040 >> 16) & 0x7FFF;
}
```

outputs `0x41c6` and Xor'ing that key It won't give anything understandable and even useful

```
code = [
    0x28,0xBF,0x16,0x68,0x36,0x19,0xA0,0x5B,
    0x4D,0xD3,0xCE,0x3A,0x25,0x52,0xE7,0x99,
    0xA5,0xED,0x9B,0xE1,0x82,0x30,0x44,0x49,
    0x6E,0x27,0xE1,0x47,0x3B,0x19,0x10,0x37,
    0x6D,0xA9,0xEC,0x4E,0x7A,0xC0,0xDA,0xEC,
    0x89,0x29,0x72,0x3C,0x31,0xC5,0x90,0x39,
    0xEA,0x92,0xAC,0x15,0xDE,0x3C,0x3F,0x69,
    0x82,0x8D,0xD2,0xF7,0x13,0xF6,0xE8,0xBE,
    0xBB,0x4D,0x60,0x7B,0x1C,0x55,0x3C,0x6F,
    0x7D,0xC2,0xD2,0xF3,0xEC,0x43,0xEF,0x5B,
    0x4D,0xAF,0x64,0x15,0x00,0x84,0xDC,0x96,
    0xE1,0xF1,0x36,0x1E,0x21,0xC6,0x7A,0xB9,
    0xA4,0xB4,0x98,0xC9,0x0B,0xE9,0x5F,0x82,
    0xB4,0x39,0xB9,0x44,0x51,0xF2,0x66,0xB5,
    0x23,0x80,0xC8,0x14,0xA4,0xF0,0x14,0x5B,
    0x80,0x85,0x81,0xA5,0xB7,0xFB,0x9D,0x7E,
    0x58,0x9B,0x2B,0x23,0x88,0x1C,0x56,0x33,
    0xBB,0xAA,0x18,0x8D,0x8C,0xDE,0x35,0xD8,
    0xF6,0xF8,0xFD,0x3A,0xEB,0x6D,0xD0,0xD2,
    0x2F,0xEA,0xA6,0xB6,0xAE,0x85,0x30,0xB8,
    0xB3,0x0E,0xDC,0x56,0xB0,0x09,0xE8,0x5F,
    0xFB,0xD9,0xE7,0x47,0xFF,0xC3,0x6C,0x8F,
    0x18,0x19,0x4F,0x70,0x45,0xE8,0xF6,0x6,
    0xC2,0x7B,0x4D,0x43,0x4F,0xE8,0xBE,0xEA,
    0xcb,0x87,0xce,0xb3
]

key = [0x41,0xc6]*98

code = ""

for i in range(196):
    code+=chr(code[i]^key[i])
```

what is this line of code really does in this context :

```
if ( ((unsigned int (__fastcall *)(char *, size_t))v14)(a2[1], v5) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sub_1169` is actually an LCG based random number generator. `sub_1155` sets the seed value for this LCG. So `sub_1155` is similar to `srand` and `sub_1169` is `rand`

Because of this the xor key is not the same for every byte.

```
srand(seed);
for ( k = 0; k <= 196; ++k )
{
  v9 = rand();
  v8[k] ^= v9;
}
```

Now

```
v14 = (int (__fastcall *)(char *, int))v8;
```

This means we are assigning byte data pointed by `v8` as function or code - specifically a function that takes a string and an int as a param and returns an int. Something like

```
bool verify_flag(char *flag, int len);
```

So `v8` is some sort of shellcode which is decoded in the xor fashion as above. Later that function is called to verify `argv[1]`

```
if ( v12(argv[1], v5) )
  puts("Good password!");
else
  puts("Invalid password!");
```

The first step of getting the shellcode decoded correctly is to figure out the input that calculates some sort of "checksum" which when used as seed to `srand` will decode to perfect x86_64 code. This is the "checksum" logic.

```
seed = 0x7FFFFFFF;
for ( i = 0; ; ++i )
{
    v3 = i;
    if ( v3 >= strlen(argv[1]) )
    break;
    seed += i * argv[1][i];
}
```

Additionally the binary sets up some `mod` based constraints that will help you figure out the correct checksum using z3.

```
from z3 import *
# https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30303/z3-is-unable-to-predict-the-operand
v7 = [123, 456, 789, 987, 654, 321]
v6 = [92, 29, 380, 2, 497, 296]
arrl = 14
argv1 = [BitVec(f'a{i}', 32) for i in range(arrl)]

solver = Solver()
v18 = BitVecVal(0x7fffffff, 32)

for i in range(arrl):
    solver.add(argv1[i] < 128)
    solver.add(argv1[i] > 32)
    v18 += i*argv1[i]

for i in range(6):
    solver.add(URem(v18, v7[i]) == v6[i])

print(solver.check())
print("".join(map(chr, [solver.model()[argv1[i]].as_long()
      for i in range(arrl)])))
```

Once you know an input that will produce the correct seed for `srand` such that `rand` generates the correct order of values for `v8` shellcode to be decoded correctly.

You can then run and dump this decoded shellcode or xor it statically with correct `rand` values.

This shellcode similarly can be analysed with IDA and modelled with z3. Its a simple xor of 2 buffers and then compare with a static buffer.
Unrelated to the answer, I have solved it with angr [here](https://gist.github.com/sudhackar/ad9c15851f274b3248ef1645abee9ae8#file-sol-py)

Comment: That's great, thank you, what was the seed number ?